# Dynamic web page scraping using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyqt4

I am running below code, but i am getting an `empty list`. Can you please help me in find out the issue.

execution: `xvfb-run python dynamic_scrapy.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
import bs4 as bs


class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/"
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
js_test = soup.find_all('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test)
```

Comment: have you tried printing `source`. Are you getting any data?

Comment: As i see, this is not a dynamic content as class `jstest` exists in the source.

Comment: please inspect this *Look at you shinin!* these line.

Comment: if you do view page source. Please find out these code:   <p class='jstest' id='yesnojs'>y u bad tho?</p>
  <script>
     document.getElementById('yesnojs').innerHTML = 'Look at you shinin!';
  </script>

Comment: if i do print(source) i am getting error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u1d90' in position 6781: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @SatishGarg can you please help me to  make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `QString` into `string` to pass it into `BeautifulSoup`. You can do something like this :

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
import bs4 as bs

class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/"
client_response = Client(url)

source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
source_utf = unicode(source.toUtf8(), encoding="UTF-8") # Added
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source_utf, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find_all('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test)
```

This will result in :

```
[<p class="jstest" id="yesnojs">Look at you shinin!</p>]
```

Comment: getting error: NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: You using python3 ?

Comment: can you please help me.

Comment: my new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188569/flipkart-dynamic-website-scrapping-using-python

Comment: can you please help me with these. i am struggling last five days

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using `PyQt4` ?

Comment: No, i am new to python. After i research i got some sample code and  i am playing with that. Is there any way to get the data from flipkart?

Comment: Yes, there are more sophisticated and simpler tools then that such as scrapy and selenium to do that.

Comment: okay, if you have working example code can you provide that. it's not possible to do using PyQt4?

Comment: my new question using selenium http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206630/scraping-data-from-flipkart-using-python-selenium