# scraping data from flipkart using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below code gives few of values it's not displaying all values in the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles")
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a""").click()
timeout = 20
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("iUmrbN")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

I am getting output like below and error also showing how to solve these problem

> ```
>   Sony Xperia XZs
>     Moto g5 Plus
>     Swipe Elite Sense
>     OPPO F3 Plus (Gold, 64 GB)
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>     SAMSUNG On Nxt
>     Swipe Elite Max (Onyx Black, 32 GB)
>     Lenovo K5 Note (4GB)
>     Zenfone 3 Laser
>
>
>
>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File ".\ff1.py", line 9, in <module>
>         print(post.text)
>       File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement
>     .py", line 73, in text
>         return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
>       File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement
>     .py", line 491, in _execute
>         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>       File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.
>     py", line 238, in execute
>         self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       File "C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandl
>     er.py", line 193, in check_response
>         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>     selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to
>     the page document
>       (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT
> ```
>
> 6.2.9200 x86_64)